# Injecting Html code in a dynamic Web Page

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events, event-listener

I need to inject some Html code into web pages that launch in browser.
Is there any way to do it?

> For example: I need to add a button dynamically at the bottom of a web page at load event
>   of a web site.

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Yes you can, performing this with JavaScript, listening for the right event and binding your action to this event.

Comment: Please give an example of code if possible

Comment: I cannot provide any example since you did not gone further in your explainations : add your relevant HTML code, a quick text for the context of your problem, the result expected, ...

Answer (score 0):

You can add html code using javaScript.

```
document.getElementById("your div id name here").innerHTML = "<button>TEST</button>";
```

To have it execute when your page is loaded you can put it into a function and have it executed onload:

```
function addButton() {
    document.getElementById("your div id name here").innerHTML = "<button>TEST</button>";
}
```

and call your function onload like this in your html body tag:

```
<body onload="addButton()">
```